# MySQL Query ORDER BY with modulus

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

My SELECT query

```
SELECT ID, NAME  FROM TBL_USER ORDER BY ID % 2, ID % 3
```

OUTPUT:

```
   ID   |  NAME 
--------|---------
    6   |   AB
    12  |   BC
    4   |   XY
    10  |   YZ
    2   |   C1
    8   |   C2
    3   |   A3
    9   |   MN
    1   |   K2
    7   |   WQ
    13  |   OP
    5   |   HJ 
    11  |   KN
```

I'm confused about how ORDER BY works with MODULUS(%). How this order generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change the query to

```
SELECT ID, NAME, ID %2, ID %3  FROM TBL_USER ORDER BY ID % 2, ID % 3
```

to include the values the ORDER BY operates on it becomes clear:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+
| ID   | NAME | ID %2 | ID %3 |
+------+------+-------+-------+
|    6 | AB   |     0 |     0 |
|   12 | BC   |     0 |     0 |
|    4 | XY   |     0 |     1 |
|   10 | YZ   |     0 |     1 |
|    2 | C1   |     0 |     2 |
|    8 | C2   |     0 |     2 |
|    9 | MN   |     1 |     0 |
|    3 | A3   |     1 |     0 |
|    1 | K2   |     1 |     1 |
|    7 | WQ   |     1 |     1 |
|   13 | OP   |     1 |     1 |
|    5 | HJ   |     1 |     2 |
|   11 | KN   |     1 |     2 |
+------+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: THANKS! ... great answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you understand how [MOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) works, here's the table showing that the values are actually in the correct order. You could generate this yourself by changing your select statement to be:

```
SELECT ID, ID % 2, ID % 3, NAME FROM TBL_USER ORDER BY ID % 2, ID % 3;

   ID   |  ID % 2  |  ID % 3  |  NAME 
--------|----------|----------|--------
    6   |     0    |     0    |   AB
    12  |     0    |     0    |   BC
    4   |     0    |     1    |   XY
    10  |     0    |     1    |   YZ
    2   |     0    |     2    |   C1
    8   |     0    |     2    |   C2
    3   |     1    |     0    |   A3
    9   |     1    |     0    |   MN
    1   |     1    |     1    |   K2
    7   |     1    |     1    |   WQ
    13  |     1    |     1    |   OP
    5   |     1    |     2    |   HJ 
    11  |     1    |     2    |   KN
```